# ASP.net C# Error when passing text to Dropdownlist, which uses an Enum as its datasource list

Tags: c#, asp.net

(Asp.net/C# VS2008)
I have a datagrid populated by a database and when pressing Edit, a form opens and populates fields/controls from that datagrid line.
My issue lies when trying to populate a dropdownlist box, which has a datasource from an ENum List.
I Just cannot get the text from the datagrid cell to show up in the ddL, it should also equal one of the Enum Items and auto select it.
My Code
Pull from the datagrid cell gives me “Low”
ddl_reg.Text = e.Item.Cells[25].Text;

```
    public void Populate_regstatus_dropdownlist()
{
    //if (!IsPostBack)
    //{
    //    ddl_reg.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(regstatus));
    //    ddl_reg.DataBind();
    //}
    //if (!IsPostBack)
    //{
    //    foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(regstatus)))
    //    {
    //        ddl_reg.Items.Add(new ListItem(Enum.GetName(typeof(regstatus), value), value.ToString()));
    //    }
    //}
    ddl_reg.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(regstatus ));
    //ddl_reg.DataValueField = regstatus;
    //ddl_reg.DataTextField = "Low";
    //ddl_reg .SelectedItem = Enum.GetName(typeof (regstatus ));
    ddl_reg.DataBind();
    //ddl_reg.SelectedIndex = ddl_reg.Items.IndexOf(ddl_reg.Items.FindByText("Low"));


}
public enum regstatus
{
    NotSelected,
    Low,
    Medium,
    High
}
```

Error received is;

ddl_reg' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

I am new to C# but through searching your site i realise this means the value is not seen or has not been pulled and would really apreciate some help, or pointing in the right direction, cheers.

Comment: What happens if you give each of the enums a value? Not sure it will help, just curious.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the drop down list doesn't contain the item you are passing. You may check it before changing the selected value. Other chances are that the value you are getting from `e.Item.Cells[25].Text` may contain spaces, so you may trim before setting it to the drop down.

```
 if (ddl_reg.Items.FindByText("Low") != null)
            {

                ddl_reg.Text = e.Item.Cells[25].Text;
            }
            else
            {
                //Not found
            }
```

Comment: Hi, Adding values to the enums did'nt work.I added Trim as it pulls from the datagrid.<br>dl_rag.Text = (e.Item.Cells[25].Text.Trim() ); "returns no data" so using<br>ddl_rag .DataTextField = e.Item.Cells[25].Text.Trim(); which returns 'Low'<br>this the correct setting to use?<br>The DB/field used for the Regstatus i chose to set all records to Low for now, so the data is there, i now receive error "DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Low'. , again i cannot get the text from the grid to say, i equal a value in the enum list so show it in the DDL box.

Comment: Think I have sorted it,
Added a variable String “regstatustext” at page load
Then 
regstatustext = e.Item.Cells[25].Text.Trim ();    where it pulls from the datagrid,then placed the variable into the item list compare statement<br>
        'public void Populate_regstatus_dropdownlist()
    {
        ddl_reg.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(regstatus ));
        ddl_reg.DataBind();
        ddl_reg.SelectedIndex = ddl_reg.Items.IndexOf(ddl_reg.Items.FindByText(regstatustext));'
    }
<br>
Thanks again to the site and replies, works so it can stay in ;p